How do I run a Python application as a process?
I received a test task that says that my Python application should run as a process and not as a Docker container, what does this mean? Thank you in advance.
I tried to find the answer on the Internet, but I couldn't find it.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
